# Form_validation errors into array

Tags: codeigniter

I have a code for form validating in my CodeIgniter app:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|valid_email|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // some errors
}
else
{
    // do smth
    $response = array(
        'message' => "It works!"
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

The form is AJAX-based, so frontend have to receive a JSON array with form errors, for example:

```
array (
  'email' => 'Bad email!',
  'password' => '6 symbols only!',
)
```

**How to get such list or array with form validation errors in CodeIgniter?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Form Validation - Get the Result as "array" Instead of "string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468139/codeigniter-form-validation-get-the-result-as-array-instead-of-string)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just echo `validation_errors()` from your controller.

have your javascript `place` it in your view.

*PHP*

```
// controller code
if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
{
    //save stuff
}
else
{
    echo validation_errors();
}
```

*Javascript*

```
// jquery
$.post(<?php site_url('controller/method')?>, function(data) {
  $('.errors').html(data);
});
```

If you really want to use JSON, jquery automatically parses JSON. You can loop through it and `append` into your html.

---

in case you need validation errors as array you can append this function to the form_helper.php

```
if (!function_exists('validation_errors_array')) {

   function validation_errors_array($prefix = '', $suffix = '') {
      if (FALSE === ($OBJ = & _get_validation_object())) {
        return '';
      }

      return $OBJ->error_array($prefix, $suffix);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

#### application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
  function __construct($config = array())
  {
    parent::__construct($config);
  }

  function error_array()
  {
    if (count($this->_error_array) === 0)
      return FALSE;
    else
      return $this->_error_array;
  }
}
```

Then you could try the following from your controller:

```
$errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
```

Reference: [validation_errors as an array](http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/10/get-codeigniter-form-validation-errors-as-an-array/)

Comment: It's a protected variable though so that won't work, therefor as your reference states - override form_validation and return it trough error_array()

Comment: $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array(); this works well

Comment: fyi, the reference link is dead now (2nd august 2022)

Answer (score 19):

If you prefer a library method, you can extend the Form_validation class instead.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function error_array() {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }

}
```

and subsequently call it in your controller/method.

```
$errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
```

Answer (score 12):

Using the latest version of codeigniter:

```
print_r($this->form_validation->error_array());
```

returns:

```
array("field"=>"message","field2"=>"message2");
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use...

```
$errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've extended form validation helper:

```
if ( ! function_exists('validation_errors_array'))
{
    function validation_errors_array()
    {
        if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
        {
            return '';
        }
        // No errrors, validation passes!
        if (count($OBJ->_error_array) === 0)
        {
            return '';
        }
        // Generate the error string
        $array = '';
        foreach ($OBJ->_error_array as $key => $val)
        {
            if ($val != '')
            {
                $array[$key]= $val;
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to return json formated object: echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); but you must have php 5.3. if your php < 5.3: echo json_encode($array);

Answer (score 1):

from : http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/10/get-codeigniter-form-validation-errors-as-an-array/

By default, the Codeigniter Form Validation errors are returned as a string:

return validation_errors();;

Answer (score 0):

In CI 4 I found this inside the form_helper.php

```php
if (! function_exists('validation_errors')) {
    /**
     * Returns the validation errors.
     *
     * First, checks the validation errors that are stored in the session.
     * To store the errors in the session, you need to use `withInput()` with `redirect()`.
     *
     * The returned array should be in the following format:
     *     [
     *         'field1' => 'error message',
     *         'field2' => 'error message',
     *     ]
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    function validation_errors()
    {
        session();

        // Check the session to see if any were
        // passed along from a redirect withErrors() request.
        if (isset($_SESSION['_ci_validation_errors']) && (ENVIRONMENT === 'testing' || ! is_cli())) {
            return $_SESSION['_ci_validation_errors'];
        }

        $validation = Services::validation();

        return $validation->getErrors();
    }
}
```

You can implement this on views like this

```php
# Views/example.php
<?= helper('form'); ?>

<form>
    ...
    <?php foreach(validation_errors() as $field_name => $error_message): ?>
        <?= "$field_name = $error_message <br>" ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution I like best doesn't involve adding a function anywhere or extending the validation library:

```
$validator =& _get_validation_object();
$error_messages = $validator->_error_array;
```

Reference: http://thesimplesynthesis.com/post/how-to-get-form-validation-errors-as-an-array-in-codeigniter/

You should be able to call this at any point in your code. Also, it's worth noting there is a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468139/codeigniter-form-validation-get-the-result-as-array-instead-of-string) that discusses this as well.

Comment: Newest CodeIgniter protects _error_array property. "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property..." You could extend it (MY_Form_validation) and set a new public property/method to _error_array I suppose. But this solution no longer works.

Comment: Yes it throws an error Cannot access protected property CI_Form_validation::$_error_array